# How can you import express modules as a function using es6 syntax?

Tags: node.js, express, ecmascript-6, babeljs

In the current version of node, importing modules as functions looks like this:

```
// case 1:
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session)

// case: 2
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
```

However, I am using es2015 syntax in my express server, which looks like this:

```
import MongoStore from 'connect-mongo'
import LocalStrategy from 'passport-local'
```

How can I pass session as a function parameter to the import statement, or append the Strategy method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For MongStore, you just need to execute the function and pass the session.

```
import MongoStore from 'connect-mongo'

var mongoStore = MongoStore(session);
```

For LocalStrategy you can do the following:

```
import { Strategy as LocalStrategy} from 'passport-local'
```

Comment: That really helped me! Thanks!